# Use vue-resource within vueify component

Tags: browserify, vue.js

I'd like to use the vue-resource $http methods within the script tag of my vueify component but I always get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

My guess would be that the "this" keyword doesn't work (wouldn't know why) or the module isn't installed correctly (although it should be, checked that). My vue-component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <!-- just displaying the data -->
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        data: function () {
            return {
                foo: "bar"
            }
        },

        ready: function() {
            // the error occurs on the next line
            this.$http.get('/api/users', function(data){
                this.$set('users', data);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was quite simple, I had to `require('vue')` in the component as well. I really did not think about this because I'm quite new to browser-/vueify.

The working code looks like this for anyone wondering:

```html
<script>
    var Vue = require('vue');

    module.exports = {
        data: function () {
            return {
                message: "Hello World!"
            }
        },

        ready: function() {
            var _self = this;
            Vue.http.get('/api/users', function(data){
                _self.$set('users', data);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: here is how I setup the whole dependencies and modules in my main.js file

```js
// require dependencies
var Vue = require('vue');
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');
var VueResource = require('vue-resource');

// use vue-router and vue-resource
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueResource);

// Laravel CSRF protection
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.getElementById('token').getAttribute('value');

// Routing
var router = new VueRouter();

var App = Vue.extend();

// start router in element with id of app
router.start(App, '#app');
```

Comment: Where are you requiring the vue-resource? can you share the code?

Comment: I edited the answer and everything should be answered right there. The main.js file is my starting point for browserify in laravel elixir.

Comment: it is helpful! you know there arent many examples about this matter.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, and yes unfortunately there aren't many examples for vueify.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer . I've been scratching my head to make this work using vueify

Answer (score 3):

FYI, for your .vue file, you don't have to require Vue. Instead you can reference the instance like this:

```
this.$http.get(...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right but for some reason it didn't work like that back then although it should've.